# SASS - Transition mixin with var args and shared args

Tags: sass, mixins

Here's what I'm trying to do, I'd like to create a mixin that allows a variable number of properties, and also allows me to use single DRY vals for (in this example) a transition.
So I could say, "transition the box-shadow, border, and width @ .2s with a ease-in."

Here's some pretty serious psuedo-code off the top of my head. The part I'm most unsure about is how to take the list so that it compiles in the proper way. I wasn't sure if append would be the right way, or if I needed to concatenate a string var, or what?

```
/* move object*/
.moveit{
    @include grouped-trans((box-shadow, border, width), 0.2s, ease-in);
}

/* mixin */
@mixin grouped-trans($list, $time, $ease)
{
    @each $prop in $list {
        //transition: append($prop, $time, $ease);
        // - or -
        //$tmp_var + $list, $time, $ease;
}
```

I know there are ways to incorporate variable args using methods like string interpolation #{} and including '...' as a parameter. But I - ideally - would like to find a way to execute this in the way I described.

Comment: Note that if you specify multiple properties in `transition-property` and only one value in each of the other properties (e.g. `transition-duration`), that value will be repeated for each one property. This would mean no need for a loop and shorter code as the list of properties to transition increases.

Comment: @JordanGray that is actually what I want. I was hoping to keep the shorthand notation for transition leveraging something like a loop, so that it didn't require I type out each transition-property, transition-duration, and transition-timing-function out individually.

Comment: Is there a reason to not use `transition: all .2s ease-in`?

Comment: @bookcasey my current configuration requires me to exclude a couple props from transitioning. Otherwise, yeah I would have just used a simple 'transition all'

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you build the mixin you're looking for. Note that this does require use of [Compass](http://compass-style.org/), but it's silly to use Sass without using Compass.

```
@import "compass";

@mixin grouped-trans($list, $time, $ease) {
  @include transition-property($list);
  @include transition-duration($time);
  @include transition-timing-function($ease);
}

.moveit {
  @include grouped-trans((box-shadow, border, width), 0.2s, ease-in);
}
```

The above SCSS will compile to the following CSS:

```
.moveit {
  -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow, border, width;
  -moz-transition-property: box-shadow, border, width;
  -o-transition-property: box-shadow, border, width;
  transition-property: box-shadow, border, width;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering how thats not possible in plain sass....cause I don't currently use compass. Regardlesss this is awesome, thanks for bumping an old post.